# How to correctly use NDB Query AND / OR

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm not sure if I'm constructing the query with `AND` and `OR` properly. When I query to just match tag, I get a handful of matching videos. But when I try the second query, (to make sure that a video isn't related to itself), the query returns all videos.

**Update**: I'm looking to return videos that have at least one of the same tags as `video` in question, but the list returned does not include `video`. Basically a related_videos feature.

```py
from solveforx.lib.moonshots import Video
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

video = Video.query().get()
tags = video.tags or []

for tag in tags:
  print Video.query(Video.tags == tag).count() # returns 1
  print "-------"
  print Video.query(Video.tags == tag and Video.key != video.key) # returns total videos - 1
  print "========"
  # also tried this
  # print Video.query(Video.tags == tag, ndb.AND(Video.key != moonshot.key)).count() # returns 0
  # print Video.query(ndb.AND(ndb.AND(Video.tags == tag), ndb.AND(Video.key != video.key) )).count()
```

Looking at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#nest_and_or) on this, but not sure how the operators are working.

Comment: Mehul, I'm a little unclear, what is the result you expect from the second conditional query? Your comments show both queries return 1. Which one is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question with what I was actually intending to do. Also going to answer my own question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`AND` takes at least two parameters. You should do:

```
Video.query(ndb.AND(Video.tags == tag, Video.key != video.key))
```

From the link that you posted you can see more examples on how to combine it with `ndb.OR` as well.

Answer (score 5):

This worked:

```py
for tag in tags:
  Video.query(Video.tags == tag, Video.key != video.key)
```